# Meaning of the kanji 目娱乐节今日?

Tags: characters

I am also trying to figure out the meaning of the kanji on one of my T-shirts:

[image]

Here is what I got in pleco:

[image]

From this I could only make out "I'm looking forward to an entertaining festival today", but I'm sure that's wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: That's Japanese.

Comment: I know, i used the kanji tag though in my post because kanji are characters borrowed from Chinese so theoretically knowing the Chinese meaning of them should be enough to predict the meaning in Japanese even though the pronunciation is different. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it's not Japanese either, it's gibberish

Comment: How do you know it's jibberish? Did an English speaker do a poor translation? If so, then how should the kanji on the t-shirt be properly assembled for the intended meaning on the t-shirt to make sense?

Comment: And Chinese characters can mean completely different things in japanese. Examples: Toilet paper (Ch) <-> letter (J), boring (Ch) <-> free of charge (J), and more.

Comment: Can you post the kanji/hanzi for the examples you quote here? Thanks.

Comment: Anyways, perhaps someone ought to migrate this question to Japanese stack exchange (didn't realize there was one at the time of the post). Thanks.

Comment: SuperDry is a British company that uses machine translated Chinese and Japanese to decorate its products: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperGroup#Image . The kanji I mentioned is 手紙, i was actually wrong about the second example 無料, which just doesn't mean anything in Chinese.

Comment: @JackMaddington It's not Japanese, seems to be simplified Chinese. But the whole sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2694607515?pn=0& it would seem that the words are of no meaning at all!

Comment: @JackMaddington The proper order should be 今日娱乐节目 -- entertaiment program of today.

Comment: Please post answers instead of comments, if you're answering, so that the OP can accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今日娱乐节目in plain English means 'Today's entertainment programmes' '节目'usually means TV Programmes.

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean anything. As mentioned by the founder of the brand mentioned in the interview, those Chinese characters just for aesthetics reason.

Comment: You could identify the proper order of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding: it should meaning "今日娱乐节目".

Answer (score 0):

This T-shirt has printed the words in a  wrong order.It should be :今日娱乐节目
（today entertainment program）

Comment: Someone should migrate this to the Japanese Language site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the creator want to say " see entertainment festival today" so he put it into google translate or see dictionary word by word, but he doesn't realize the grammar was totally wrong. After that some Chinese point that problem but too late, so the only thing can do is refuse to admit that error, just telling people that Chinese was mean less or just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless machine translation. If you see the news report at http://www.japanprobe.com/2011/10/16/superdry-popular-uk-fashion-brand-uses-gibberish-japanese/ the company deliberately inserted gibberish Japanese text in a similar fashion to the Japanese practices of inserting nonsense English texts to decorate products. 今日/娱乐/节目 would be correct Chinese.